# Javascript is not able to load the list of HTML files in Static Website

Tags: javascript, html, azure-static-website-hosting

I have a static website, hosted on Azure (with free plan). The following is the structure of my website:

[image]

**Goal:** I want that the webpage `all-travel-blogs.html` display the titles of all the travel blogs present inside the folder `travel-blogs`. To achieve this, I have the following `javascript` present in the file `bloglist.js` file:

```
function getBlogList() {
   var blogsFolder = './travel-blogs';
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
           if (xhr.status === 200) {
               var blogList = document.getElementById('blogList');
               var blogFiles = xhr.responseText.split('\n');
               var blogHTML = '';
               for (var i = 0; i < blogFiles.length; i++) {
                   if (blogFiles[i]) {
                       var blogTitle = getBlogTitle(blogFiles[i]);
                       var blogIntro = getBlogIntro(blogFiles[i]);
                       blogHTML += '<div><a href="' + blogsFolder + '/' + blogFiles[i] + '">' + blogTitle + '</a><p>' + blogIntro + '</p></div>';
                   }
               }
               blogList.innerHTML = blogHTML;
           } else {
               console.error('Failed to load blog files');
           }
       }
   };
   xhr.open('GET', blogsFolder, true);
   xhr.send();
}

function displayBlogList() {
   getBlogList();
}

function getBlogTitle(blogFile) {
   // Extract the title from the file name
   return blogFile.substring(0, blogFile.indexOf('.html'));
}

function getBlogIntro(blogFile) {
   // Get the first <p> element from the blog file
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', './travel-blogs/' + blogFile, false);
   xhr.send();
   var blogHTML = xhr.responseText;
   var parser = new DOMParser();
   var doc = parser.parseFromString(blogHTML, 'text/html');
   return doc.querySelector('p').innerHTML;
}
```

**Code of the HTML Page to list all Travel blogs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Travel Blog List</title>
    <script src="./bloglist.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="displayBlogList()">
    <h1>Travel Blog List</h1>
    <div id="blogList"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PROBLEM:** Since, the webpage was not displaying the list of blogs, I opened the **Inspect** webpage and found that I am getting following errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/github-client/Website/Eterna-Bootstrap-Theme-based-website/blogs/blogs/travel-blogs' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

As per the suggestion, I installed the **Live Server** extension to test running the webpage on a local server. But still it is not working as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: "I have a static website, hosted on Azure (with free plan)" — The error message indicates that you are testing it by loading the files from your hard disk directly into the browser and **not** using Azure (maybe you plan to use Azure for your production environment, but you aren't using it for the test that is causing you problems).

Comment: @Quentin: Even at Azure, it does not work. For testing, I installed the Live Server extension in Visual studio and tried to run the Webpage on the localhost, still it did not work. I have provided a new screenshot.

Comment: Those are a completely different set of error messages indicating a completely different problem. Or, in this case, two completely different problems. 404 Not Found means the URL is wrong. Either (a) Your logic for calculating the URL based on the contents of ./travel-blogs is wrong or (b) that URL doesn't return the data you expect. There's no way for us to debug it with the information you've provided. (So the question should remain closed).

Comment: Your second problem is a [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Answer (score 0):

The error message you mentioned indicates that the browser is blocking access to a file loaded by Azure Static Web App from the local file system due to the absence of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. This happens because of the `CORS` (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) specification, which prevents browsers from accessing resources from other origins (such as different domains or file systems) without permission from the server.

**Using Azure, you [can set up global headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#global-headers) to ensure that our requests are sent to the server in accordance with CORS rules.**

Example:

```json
{
  "globalHeaders": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why your Azure web app is attempting to load content using the `file://` protocol (see: `file://C:/github...` in error message). This is an incorrect approach for any website, as it only works on a local machine. Unfortunately, I have not had the opportunity to test this behavior on Azure. My answer is solely based on my web development experience.

Comment: Since my website is hosted as Static website on Azure (since it's free), can I use web server?

Comment: I have modified my answer. --- In the original wording, I wanted to emphasize that the `file://` protocol has never been appropriate for a website because it only works on the server machine. If you try to access the website from another machine, it won't be able to find the file. Instead, the `http://` protocol should be used. --- With Azure, there is no need for an additional web server. I just mentioned an example that is capable of serving the `http://` protocol.

Comment: I have rephrased my answer to give more attention to explaining CORS rules. Nevertheless, I still do not understand why Azure web app needs to use the `file://` protocol. Why can't it access another HTML file/folder with the `http://` protocol?

Comment: "I'm not sure why your Azure web app is attempting to load content using the file:// protocol" — The only explanation I can think of, given the code shown, is that the OP is experiencing his problem when testing locally before deploying to Azure.

Comment: @Quentin: Right. The screenshots that I have posted are taken while testing locally. Once the things work fine locally then, I commit my changes to Azure.

Comment: @rozsazoltan: I tried to run using a local server but still it not working. I have provided an Update with new screenshot in my original post.

Comment: If I see it correctly, you accidentally inserted `<!DOCTYPE><html>` at the end of the link. As a result, the page cannot find the file on the path and displays a 404 error code.

Answer (score -1):

Try inserting the data you would like into a `<div>`. For example:

```
let my_data = "test"; 
document.getElementById("div-id").innerHTML = my_data;
```